# JBoss migration from v4 to v7, supporting EJB2.1

Tags: java, jboss, migration, ejb

I have migration project which i have to start to migrate EJB2.1 enterprise web application from version 4 to version 7.1Beta(Tesla) that supports EJB2.1, I am new to migration stuffs and have looked up online but not successful in finding information regarding migration from  jboss v4 to v7 migration.

Would appreciate any useful pointers.

Comment: do share your thoughts as comments if you do not have answer, may be it can help.

Comment: @casperOne: I would appreciate your suggestions to improve this question, if not, may be migrate it to different stackexchange site, let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest by starting out migrating to EJB 3.  It is a tedious process, but pays off in a code base that is much easier to manage.

jBoss 7x is a completely different beast than the 4.x version.  The biggest change is in how class loading is handled (see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-HowdoImigratemyapplicationfromJBossAS5orAS6toJBossAS7%3F)  and how the application needs to be packaged (all in one EAR as opposed to multiple jars/wars).

Here is an example of how an ear file should be structured:

```
myApp.ear
     + ---- lib
     |       |------- third_party_libraries_such_as_commons-lang-2.4.jar
     |       |------- Any_Entity_Beans.jar
     |       + ------ Other_Library_files.jar
     |
    +----- META-INF
    |       +-- persistence.xml (.. possibly other config files)
    |       
    |
    | ---- application_1.jar
    | ---- application_2.jar
    + ---- webapp_1.war
```

Comment: thank you Helga for the information, can you provide details based on your experience based on your work with migrating ejb application from ejb2 application from jboss v4 to jboss v7?

Comment: It has been a while.... basically it involves moving from XML descriptors to Annotation and moving entity beans to Pojos.  This article describes an approach similar to the one I took. http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/04/25/ejb3_migration/